# Datatables column search returns full set of data

Tags: javascript, datatables

Using datatables `columns().seach().draw()` fails and I'm unable to find the mistake.

```
columnas = Array.apply(null, {length: 6}).map(Number.call, Number)
datatable.columns(columnas).every(function(){
    that = this;
    $('input').on('keyup change', function(){
        console.log('keyup')
        console.log(that.search(this.value));
        that.search(this.value).draw();
    });
});
```

It seems that the search will always return all of the rows.

Also, `console.log(that.search($(this).val()).rows().count())` returns full data set count,

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are some typo mistake in your code, try to fix that and then try. 
1. change `that = this` to `var that = this`.
2. change `that.search(this.value).draw()` to `that.search($(this).val()).draw();`;

Final solution should be like this :

```
var columnas = Array.apply(null, {length: 6}).map(Number.call, Number)
datatable.columns(columnas).every(function(){
    var that = this;
    $('input').on('keyup change', function(){
        console.log('keyup')
        console.log(that.search(this.value));
        that.search($(this).val()).draw();
    });
});
```

Fore more info :  [see this link](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns().every()#highlighter_860255)

Hope this work for you.

Comment: No, console says everything is OK.